# How do I turn a tuple of numbers into a list of binary numbers that show if that number is present

Tags: python, pandas

So i've got a column in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
(1,6,3,7,5)
```

and I want to turn it into this:

```
[1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
```

where each number in the tuple gets turned into a 1 in the index of the list.

edit:

small sample of dataframe

```
1      4687757346         True        False             True     (103, 10, 61, 236, 21)     (54, 17, 32, 38, 20)      Win
2      4673649989         True        False             True  (268, 222, 498, 161, 115)    (74, 63, 59, 238, 98)     Fail
3      4673567192        False         True            False       (7, 10, 126, 43, 90)  (203, 26, 63, 161, 412)     Fail
4      4673561860        False         True             True   (202, 102, 25, 154, 266)     (16, 61, 79, 21, 82)     Fail
```

Comment: Indexing starts from 0

Comment: Can you share a sample of the dataframe and expected output?

Comment: Also, should the length of your output list be equal to the maximum value in the input?

Comment: Yes that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) for binning, then add missing non matched values and last convert output DataFrame to lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[(1,6,3,7,5), (1,6,3,7,2,5)]})

#maximal number
maxd = max(y for x in df['col'] for y in x)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df['new'] = (pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['col']),
                  columns=mlb.classes_, 
                  index=df.index)
               .reindex(range(1, maxd+1), axis=1, fill_value=0)
               .to_numpy()
               .tolist())
print (df)
                  col                    new
0     (1, 6, 3, 7, 5)  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
1  (1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5)  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: maxd = df['col'].apply(max).max() ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
res = [0] * max(your_tuple)
[1 if index + 1 in your_tuple else 0 for index, num in enumerate(res)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
data = (1,6,3,7,5)

data_arr = []
for i in range(max(data)):
    data_arr.append(0)

for item in data:
    data_arr[item - 1] = 1

print(data_arr)
```

Comment: can you just use `max(data)`? Why are you doing that by hand?

Comment: been there, it happens

Answer (score 0):

One way using `numpy.zeros` with `numpy.add.at`:

```
def func(tups):
    arr = np.zeros(max(tups)+1, dtype=int)
    np.add.at(arr, list(tups), 1)
    return arr[1:]
```

Output for sample:

```
t = (1,6,3,7,5)
func(t)
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

Output for df:

```
df.iloc[:,[5,6]].applymap(func)
                                                   5  \
0  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   
1  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   
2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   
3  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...   

                                                   6  
0  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  
1  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  
2  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...  
3  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = (1,6,3,7,5) 
result = [(1 if i in t else 0) for i in range(1, max(t)+1)]
```

Output

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Use apply:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[(1,6,3,7,5), (1,6,3,7,2,5)]})  
length = df['col'].apply(max).max() 
df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda t: [(1 if i in t else 0) for i in range(1, length+1)] )
```

Output

```
                  col                    new
0     (1, 6, 3, 7, 5)  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
1  (1, 6, 3, 7, 2, 5)  [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```